# Recommended hardware for ffmpeg/vlc

Tags: graphics-cards, server, processor

I need to create a video matrix.
4 video HD streams in (10MB/s each, 1080p), 1 HD stream out.

This can be done with ffmpeg and vlc.

This will be done on a CLI linux server.

In test everything is working, except that the hardware is too slow for this.
Can someone confirm that the **cpu** is the bottleneck for this project? Or is this something that does it's calculations on a GPU?

Or if it's possible: what hardware setup would you recommend for this? Creating a 2x2 video matrix is the only thing that the server needs to do.

Comment: The easiest way to tell where the bottleneck is is to profile CPU, GPU, memory and IO utilisation.

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't have GPU acceleration, so I doubt it's the GPU. Try (like @Alpha3031 said) monitoring I/O, CPU, and memory resources to figure out where your bottleneck is